# Kendo UI Mobile - Rebind endless scrolling functionality to listview

Tags: jquery, kendo-mobile

I have a kendo mobile listview that uses a datasource with endless scrolling, server-side paging and filtering. Everything works as expected and the new data is populated upon changing the filter options. Here is the problem:

If the user reaches the last page of data on a filter option, then changes the filter option, the new filter option will not display the small loading image between paging requests during endless scrolling. I know this may seem trivial, but is there a workaround to have the small loading image work as expected when changing the datasource's filter options?

I am using Kendo UI Mobile v2013.1.319 and JQuery 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

You could run a [loading pop up](http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/application/loadingpopup.html#/) on the startRequest for the dataSource and hide it on the endRequest for the dataSource.